# Trying to call custom delegate method of subclass of UITextField in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, delegates

I have a custom delegate that I have created for a subclass of UITextField.  In the delegate class, I've declared an enum like this:

```
MyCustomDelegate.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "MyCustomTextField.h"



@interface MyCustomDelegate : NSObject <MyDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong)MyCustomTextField *customTextField;

@end
```

MyCustomTextField.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef enum {
    EnumTypeA,
    EnumTypeB,
    EnumTypeC,
    EnumTypeD,
    EnumTypeE
} MyEnumType;

@class MyCustomDelegate;

@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)methodA;
- (void)methodB;
@end

@interface MyCustomTextField : UITextField 

@property (nonatomic, weak)id <MyDelegate>myDelegate;
@property (nonatomic) MyEnumType enumType;

@end
```

Now, I am trying to use this enum in conjunction with my custom UITextField elsewhere in my project, like this:

MyViewController.h

```
#import "MyCustomTextField.h"
#import "MyCustomDelegate.h"

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyCustomTextField *mySampleTextField;

@end
```

MyViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.mySampleTextField setMyEnumType:EnumTypeA];

}
```

However, I am getting the error, "No visible @interface for 'MyCustomTextField' declares the selector 'setMyEnumType'".

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A delegate should be a protocol, not a class. And why do you think you set a property from the `MyCustomDelegate` class on an instance of a `MyCustomTextField` class?

Comment: The enum was initially declared inside the custom UITextField, and I then separated it from the class, and put it inside the class that implemented the protocol.  Should I leave the declaration of the enum inside the custom UITextField class?

Comment: What is the definition of `MyCustomTextField`? How have you related it to `MyCustomDelegate`?

Comment: It isn't (just) the declaration of the enum type but also the declaration of the property.

Comment: It's not the enum,, it's where the property is declared. You are trying to set the property on an instance of `MyCustomTextField` but the property is declared in the `MyCustomDelegate` class.

Comment: Reason why you have that error is bc you are setting myEnumType to the text field object, but you have this myEnumType in the delegate object.

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to do? Bc a delegate doesn't look to be happening in your code

Comment: I've updated my code to show you the .h class of my custom UITextField class.  What I did was I took out the code for the enum, and put in my delegate class which is implementing the protocol which is declared inside my custom UITextField.  What I guess I should do is put the declaration of the enum BACK into the custom UITextField?

Comment: yes, but again, it isn't the enum it is the property. You moved the property to your delegate class but you are still trying to set the property on your text field

Comment: Ok, I've made the change that you suggested, please take a look at my code, is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: You don't need `@class MyCustomDelegate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C will automatically generate setter for you based on the name of the property (`enumType`) instead of the name of type (`MyEnumType`). So your setters should be the following instead:

```
[self.mySampleTextField setEnumType:EnumTypeA];
```